# Extract Data from running dataset

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I've had a minor crisis with my sql server, involving a large portion of the data being removed. Luckily, an application I wrote was using a dataset to pull data from the server, and still has all of the old data. Is there any way I can extract this data for rentry into the database? This must be done as the application is running, as opening a new instance pulls new data from the database...

My google-fu has turned up nothing, as this is a very particular problem to have. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Apologies for the questionable tags, its hard to see where exactly this fits.

EDIT:
To clarify some confusion found in the comments, the data is absolutely within the application, however closing it will cause a loss of this data. Copying the data from the UI is what I'm trying to avoid here...as that would be massively time consuming. Thank you again for help, much appreciated.

Comment: How is the data in your application? In memory?

Comment: Presumably, though im not familiar with how the dataset functions internally

Comment: Can you write the dataset from the application to a flat file?   Copy and paste it from a screen display?

Comment: I might be able to write the dataset to another file, but I dont know how to do this. There application displays each row one at a time or so, using the display is a last resort. The time needed there would be quite large.

Comment: As @TabAlleman suggested, I would try to save my data from my dataset to any other place (flat file, other database, anywhere) so you have a backup of the data, even if it is comma delimited (or not).

Comment: Sure do, but data will be lost once the application closes

Comment: I assumed you can't restart the application or the data is gone, so changing it sounds like impossible mission. You could dump the memory using procdump, but the data might be scattered all over the place.

Comment: @JesseShellabarger So the application has displayed the data on screen and once you go through it, the application loses it? Is there any way you can save the application page (I'm assuming it's `HTML`?). Then you would have a "hard copy" of the data.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Not quite, the application uses a dataset to pull data from the database, and users can then view, edit, and insert to the data as desired. It basically allows less technical members of the team to modify data.

Comment: If the data is strings, process explorer could also be able to show them, but in that case too, it might be a big jigsaw puzzle...

Comment: Maybe doing something like ds.WriteXml(fileName); in the immediate window. not sure if it will work.

Comment: @JamesZ Unfortunately, that sounds slower than simply viewing each data row in the application and copying that into SSMS

Comment: @JesseShellabarger Without knowing the internal logic of the application we can't say for sure if the dataset is in memory or the application queries the DB for the "next page" once you try to navigate on a different page.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu It must be in memory. The database has been compromised, but all data viewed through the application is consistent with correct data. I guess im having trouble explaining it, but just trust me that its there

Comment: @JesseShellabarger If you can copy-paste it easily from the application that's probably the simplest way to do that and maybe using a text file + bcp the load it in

Comment: @JesseShellabarger If it were up to me, if the quantity of data is considerable and it's importance is significant then I'd go **first** for the **safest** solution, even if it is the most painful (time-wise) - copy paste / save page etc., in order to make sure my data is safe. Now, after trying this, if I can still access the data as it currently is, I can try to think of a fancier solution.

Comment: If your application doesn't have any built-in means of exporting the dataset, I'm afraid there's no easy "hack" to go in grab the dataset of the running application.   Can you imagine what kind of security hole it would be if there were?   You might as well start doing copy-n-paste, sounds like that's your only access point.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Your advice is solid. I'm in-fact working on that now. It will take quite a long time, however, so I'm still open to quicker solutions

Comment: Sometimes, in complex systems, problems don't have an easy fix. I would say that without access to the code, if the application needs a .dll or similar to build in order to apply changes to the logic (considering that there would be a hacker around here smart enough to make a JS plug-in to run in your page and send the data to the DB etc.), if you don't have access to the DB driver/tables which are used,**GOD and a lot more information** which tells us how the app works internally, we haven't got many chances to help. Or maybe this is just me and hopefully a more experienced developer drops by